# Faster Synchronization between two different servers

Tags: windows-xp, unix, synchronization

I am using Doors for synchronization of my project modules. However if i have to synchronize modules for two different servers located at two different locations, say from Pune to Hallstadt. What script can I use for faster transfer of zipped files whilst synchronizing?

Comment: Care to give us something useful to work with, such as what OS you're using?

Comment: The servers are on unix, while i am working on a windows XP. I want to synchronize the project modules between 2 different servers located at Germany and India using IBM Doors. However, while synchronizing, Doors takes a hell lot of time to transfer zipped files. I need a solution to reduce this transfer time significantly.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) - it would sync one directory to another, transferring only changed parts of files. There are also number of windows versions, like [cwrsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650).

EDIT: oh, you want to synchronize two unix servers. Most modern unixes already have rsync or have rsync package available. To synchronize server1 to server2 you need to execute something like that on server1:

```
rsync -razv --progress /path/to/soruce/dir/ username@server2:/path/to/destination/dir/
```

This syntax tells rsync to use ssh, so you don't need to run rsync server and transfer would be encrypted.

Comment: Yes, that is my second choice. It helps for the failed transfers as well. Would let you guys know, if anything helps. Thanks all

Comment: You'll likely want to use -a for archive mode (transfers recursively, preserves permissions, etc.) and -z to compress before transferring. See the `rsync(1)` man page for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already passing the data through a VPN, you can try this as it can provide some increase in transfer. Else you have the options of purchasing larger pipes to the locations or making the files smaller. You could try QOS, but it won't effect much unless the bottle neck is on your network which is unlikely.

Comment: You are right about the bottlenect. I suspect DOORS' fault in time consuming, that is why, I am looking for a script that could actually speed up the transfer.

Comment: Also, I have tried: Mounting a file system on other server, and transferring files using netcat. But this does not seem to be a good idea, does it?

Comment: I believe VPN won't help at all. It could only help if it would include compression, but original post described transferring zipped files, so compression won't help. VPN is a security tool, not a bandwidth accelerator.

Comment: In theory VPN would help, the same notion applies to using VNC to remote machines. VPNs can help to improve data transfer rates as they utilize data checking and transfer in a different manor than a normal transfer over the internet. For this case I believe it will boil down to the protocol you use to handle the data transfer. Netcat would be worth a try as I believe it does use a different transfer protocol than rsync. As for a script to speed up transfer speeds, the best you could do is maybe a script that shuts down other open connections.